# Why I can't grant a duchy to a count?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I have a duchy (Grand Principality of Smolensk) and 2 counties belong to me while 3 other counties to my vassals. Because I have too many duchies I was going to give one of the counties to a good ruler from my dynasty, and next grant him duchy.

This worked well in the past, but not now. After granting a county, the "Grand Landed Title" option is greyed out, the reason is I don't have a landed title which I could grant to this person.

At the same time, I can grand this duchy to one of existing counts...

Why? Is this a new game restriction?

Comment: Probably gavelkind biting you in the ass again.

Comment: How can that be related?

Comment: Because gavelkind restricts how you can give away your titles.

Comment: When you hover over the diplo option, it should give you a reason why. What does the tooltip say? In all paradox games, tooltips are your friends. I can think of a few dozen reasons why but without more info I cannot reliably answer the question. Inheritance law tho as @RossRidge said might be the reason.

Comment: @Xander I am under the impression that the greyed out tooltip says "You don't have a landed title, which you can land to this person." And OP is trying to found out why the title in question can't be given to someone.

Comment: I already don't have that save and can't tell... will share more details if i see this problem again

Answer (score 2):

Gavelkind Succession has some mechanics to avoid you giving your heir all your titles except one before you die, so you can't game the system.

> You cannot destroy titles subject to gavelkind succession (except
>   titular titles). You cannot give your primary heir more than a single
>   county. That is, you cannot grant them a duchy title or a second
>   county. (You can, however, strengthen them by granting extra castles
>   or tribes.) Furthermore, you can only give your primary heir a county
>   that they are expected to inherit.

https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Gavelkind

But it seems like you are not trying to give your heir a title, but another character. 
Does the character in  question have any traits disqualifying them?
is the duchy a regular feudal duchy?